# Should we allow users to write to database directly? How to do it correctly

Tags: design, database, security

I'm developing a new application that allows the user to do many writes. Therefore, it is very inefficient that we use our server-side to handle every write request by users. Should we allow users to write to the database directly, without going through a server process? we're using Firebase so we can write security rules easily.

If yes, how can we protect against malicious attacks? For example, some attackers may send a lot of bytes to overload the database

Comment: You're giving people public write access to the database and what you're specifically worried about is that attackers (who inherently must already have write access at this point) are trying to upload useless data?

Comment: Malicious attacks can also include someone reading data that they shouldn't be allowed to access (Which can have serious ethical and legal implications if the data belongs to another user)

Comment: While your username makes me suspect that you're not based in Europe, the proposed approach will be a clear and flagrant violation of GDPR.

Comment: @Flater: to be fair, the GDPR is only about person-related data, and the OP did not state what kind of data is stored in their database.

Comment: This question is pretty vague without knowing more details about the architecture and system. What kind of application? Desktop? Web? Mobile? All of it? Roughly, how many users? 10, 1000, >100.000? How are access rights to the DB managed? Distribution of logic between client and server? Inhouse application? Etc. Vorting to close ("needs details or clarity") until the question gets edited.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there'll be more but I'll point to three concerning points that I find especially relevant.

#### Scalability

Long story short, a wild west DB access strategy scales very bad. Economically can be unaffordable as the system grows in popularity. The more concurrency the more resources you need for each DB. To my experience, scaling out/up middlewares (or backends) is cheaper and simpler than scaling DBs. Overall in HA setups.

I can make my middleware more efficient by choosing the right stack, proper data structures, algorithms, paradigm and architecture. The more efficient I make it the cheaper will be to scale it up/out.

DBS can be tuned up to a degree, but never as much as custom developments.

If we were speaking about on-premise databases I would point to the issue of not having common connection pools. That would make the access to the DB more inefficient than going through the middleware managing one of these pools because every client results in one new connection that is never reused. This is also true for HTTP connections.

#### Vulnerability

For clients to have access to the DB they need the settings (schemas, URLs, credentials, keys, certificates, whatever). For every env.

If I manage to hack your client and get the DB settings, nobody prevents me from building my own client on top of your data, allowing me to strangle your business almost for free. You will be the one paying the expensive bills.

It's even worse, you don't have a way to know who is strangling you. You can not block me without blocking everyone else. Or you can, but for a little while, the time it takes me to adapt my client with your "fixes".

#### Abstraction

The capacity to move and change your data is also important. At some point, you might need to move from Firebase to another database system. Maybe because your business grew and Firebase felt short. In your case, the coupling between clients and DB would be so tight that the migration and the client update would result in more efforts (time and money) than only adapting a middleware.

This is especially relevant if you have to provide backward compatibility. If your clients are web apps this is not an issue but if not, the segmentation by version will make you go crazy.

Comment: I disagree with this post. While this would be an issue with most databases, Firebase does not give direct access to the database and there is some confusion between intent and context. the only way the OP is able to do this is by giving out their service credentials for the admin-sdk which is not the intended use.
The rest can be minimized and controlled with Rules and Origin policies.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that allowing direct has multiple impacts.

From a security perspective you present the database to the "public" (whatever public is in your context). With an application server inbetween you can apply much stricter network configurations.

But my main concern would be a different one. When your users connect directly to the database, without any abstraction layer inbetween, then a change on the database will result very likely in necessary changes on the user side. In my eyes, thats one of the fastest ways to maintenance hell.

So, IF you just have a small bunch of users AND you know them all personaly and see them quite regularly AND they will be able to adept quite fast when you have to change something AND the data has very low value (also from a privacy point of view), THEN i would perhaps consider a direct connection approach.

Therefore, i would not advise a direct connection. The money you save at implementation time, you will spend (and a lot of nerves) for maintenance.

warm regards
Jan

Comment: it is technically impossible to allow direct access to Firebase, just unsecured rules and poor origin policies.

Answer (score 0):

> Should we allow users to write to the database directly, without going through a server process?

If I were to hand you a diagnostic console connected to the electronic Engine Management System of your car, would you have the *faintest idea* how to enter data into it safely, without reducing your shiny, new, high-tech conveyance into a one-and-a-half ton *paperweight*?

Probably not.

Users have much the *same* lack of understanding about "how things work" inside Databases.

Allowing Users direct, unfettered, update access to *any* Database is just *asking* for Trouble (i.e. Production Incidents and service outages).  The potential trouble they can cause is *not* justifiable against the *supposed* benefits.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My question meant to ask should we allow the client-side application to write into the database directly. That is, users will interact with our buttons on the screen & the app will execute the code to write to the database for the users.

Comment: These days, I would suggest that this "thick client" model is insecure.  You should implicitly trust *nothing* from the client.  You cannot guarantee that it's /your/ program pushing updates to your database.  If you are "kind" enough to hand a malicious user connection details and credentials to get into your database, all bets are off.  Instead, have your client program communicate with a [trust-worthy] server-side component and have /that/ make the database connection and apply the changes on behalf of a properly authenticated client.

Comment: This is also disregarding the Rules and origin-based policies that Firebase has. You should never trust the client, however, if their requests meet your rules criteria, then it should be valid, the important thing is to use rules properly, it's more than a simple "allow read if auth != null".